# Bootstrap offset in wordpress shortcode (Shortcode parameters)

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, shortcode

A few days ago I learned about WordPress short-code. Now I can build any basic short-code. I was trying to implement bootstrap in my short-code. I created a short-code like this  - `[custom_post col="4" post_per_page="5"]` and it's working fine.

I'm having problems with the implementation of column offset. Suppose someone want to create 2 column layout with bootstrap class `col-sm-3` also he want offset to left 3 column, so `col-sm-offset-3`. The short-code should look like this `[custom_post col="3" offset="3" post_per_page="5"]`.

In the below code I used the offset parameter but it's not working. As the column in the loop so it takes offset with every column. In our case we have 2 column (col-sm-3), so the offset taking place in-front of those 2 column, not only with first column. 
**So how to set offset in short-code correctly ?**

Here is my sample code:

```
function CustomPost_Shortcode($atts, $content = NULL) {
    extract(shortcode_atts(array(

        'col' => '',
        'offset' => '',
        'post_per_page' => ''     
    ), $atts));

    $args = array('post_type' => 'CustomPost', 'post_per_page' => $col);

    $query = new WP_Query($args);
    $list = "";
    while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post();    
        $list .='<div class="col-sm-'.$col.' col-sm-offset-'.$offset.'>

                    <h4 class="item-header"><a href="'.get_the_permalink(). '">'.get_the_title().'</a></h4>

                    <div class="post-image">
                        '.get_the_post_thumbnail().'
                    </div>

                    <div class="post-content">
                        <p>' . get_the_excerpt().'</p>
                        <p><a href="' . get_the_permalink().'">Read More</a></p>
                    </div>
                  </div>';
    endwhile;
    wp_reset_query();
    return $list;
}

add_shortcode('custom_post', 'CustomPost_Shortcode');
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try below code to get result.

**Shortcode:**

```
[custom_post col="3" offset="3" post_per_page="5"]
```

**Code:**

```
function CustomPost_Shortcode($atts, $content = NULL) {
    extract(shortcode_atts(array(
        'col' => '',
        'offset' => '',
        'post_per_page' => ''     
    ), $atts));

    $args = array('post_type' => 'post', 'posts_per_page' => $post_per_page);

    $query = new WP_Query($args);
    $list = '';
    while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post();    
        $list .='<div class="col-sm-'.$col.' col-sm-offset-'.$offset.'">

                    <h4 class="item-header"><a href="'.get_the_permalink(). '">'.get_the_title().'</a></h4>

                    <div class="post-image">
                        '.get_the_post_thumbnail().'
                    </div>

                    <div class="post-content">
                        <p>' . get_the_excerpt().'</p>
                        <p><a href="' . get_the_permalink().'">Read More</a></p>
                    </div>
                  </div>';
    endwhile;
    wp_reset_query();
    return $list;
}

add_shortcode('custom_post', 'CustomPost_Shortcode');
```

Comment: Thank you. The $list = " "; statement was part of my code, but before posting here somehow I deleted it. Still same result. 

Actually the offset is working but not in proper way. As the the column div in the loop so the offset is taking place with every column, not with only the first column. So in the result a blank space(offset) is showing before every column.

Comment: means you need offset in 1st,3rd,5th,etc places right?

Comment: No. I want the offset in natural way. Only before the first column. 

*Apology for my English, it is not my mother language.

Comment: natural way means? so if you want offset in only first place then you can do it with custom code in shortcode

Answer (score 0):

Set the `$offset` to `0`, like this...

```
function CustomPost_Shortcode($atts, $content = NULL) {
    extract(shortcode_atts(array(
        'col' => '',
        'offset' => '',
        'post_per_page' => ''     
        ), $atts));

    $args = array('post_type' => 'CustomPost', 'post_per_page' => $col);

    $query = new WP_Query($args);
    $list = "";
    while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post();    
        $list .='<div class="col-sm-'.$col;
        if ($offset > 0) {
            $list .= ' col-sm-offset-'.$offset;
            $offset = 0;
        }
        $list .= '">

                <h4 class="item-header"><a href="'.get_the_permalink(). '">'.get_the_title().'</a></h4>

                <div class="post-image">
                    '.get_the_post_thumbnail().'
                </div>

                <div class="post-content">
                    <p>' . get_the_excerpt().'</p>
                    <p><a href="' . get_the_permalink().'">Read More</a></p>
                </div>
              </div>';
    endwhile;
    wp_reset_query();
    return $list;
}

add_shortcode('custom_post', 'CustomPost_Shortcode');
```